# Export query result mysql Terminal Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal, mamp, export-to-csv

I am trying to export the results of an `SQL` query generated via`Terminal` on a `Mac` (when I try the same procedure within `MAMP` it will only export about 200 results before it gives an error message, so if I have 1000 results having to do it 5 times is a pain).

Based on questions asked here I have tried permutations of

```
SELECT `WhateverINeed`
FROM `1911` 
INTO OUTFILE 'AnotherTest.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

So while this 'works' – `Query OK, 729 rows affected` – the file I want to create AnotherTest.csv does not appear anywhere on my system that I can see.

Comment: how about you specify the path? i.e. /Users/you/AnotherTest.csv

Comment: or check `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/[database_name]/`. you should see AnotherTest.csv there.